# How can I load an XML file across domains?

Tags: html, xml

I understand from W3schools that I cannot parse an XML file across domains for security reasons.  I have a small embedded web server with an XML file on it containing sensor data.  I'd like to pull that data into a web site using HTML, by parsing the XML file.  The web site is hosted externally on another domain.

Is there a way to copy the XML data automatically over to the same domain to get around this security limitation?  Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Can you setup a proxy on the target website (such as a PHP file that will request the XML)

Comment: I would change your title slightly. This post doesn't have anything to do with parsing. Change it to "loading XML" for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to get around this issue:

1. On the server side code from which the HTML is loaded, implement a "proxy". Basically this means download the XML to that server from the server where the XML actually "resides". You'd write this code in PHP/Java/Python/whatever server-side code you use.
2. The other thing you could do (and this is preferred if it's possible) is that you can somehow convince the server with the XML to give you the data not in XML, but in JSON. Then what you could do, is that you can write some client-side code (Javascript) to  get that directly, essentially circumventing the security limitation. This would be implemented client-side with [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_example.asp). This is not possible if the data is in XML format.

Comment: Is it not possible to load XML files from other domains using AJAX with [cross-origin resource sharing?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)